# Can you "do" or "make" a miracle?

Tags: word-usage

Can you "do" or "make" a miracle? There's an expression "work/perform miracles", but it's different. I mean managing to achieve something that is like a miracle (something good but seemingly impossible). I want to refer to a singular event rather than an ability to regularly perform exceptionally well (as in "work miracles")

Comment: Why is it 'different'? One can work or perform a single 'miracle' (perform a task that someone though was impossible, but which, clearly, was not). 'True' miracles only exist in religious stories. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Idiomatically, **work** or **perform** are the only verbs that really go with "a miracle".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A_VERB%20a%20miracle&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bis_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbe_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwork_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbeen_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwrought_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bperform_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bperformed_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bworked_VERB%20a%20miracle%3B%2Cc0)

There's nothing special about those verbs; they can certainly be used with singular miracles.

> ["That woman has worked a miracle!" he said...](https://books.google.com/books?id=0oOdDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT161&dq=%22worked%20a%20miracle%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN0Lbz39X3AhXoUt8KHTDEAq04FBDoAXoECAcQAg)

> [I am reluctant to perform a miracle that only benefits one person.](https://books.google.com/books?id=imI9DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT105&dq=%22to%20perform%20a%20miracle%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij87Kh4NX3AhXJjIkEHcmBAsE4HhDoAXoECAUQAg)